# Boost.Python and PyQt

Tags: pyqt, boost-python

How do I pass objects like QSize and QPoint between C++ and Python using Boost.Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [code](http://gitorious.org/avogadro/avogadro/blobs/e297c37550a093deaf515229a4c4c040a882d5b0/libavogadro/src/python/sip.cpp) worked.  I wasn't able to return QSize &c. by internal reference though, but returning by value worked fine.